# Transfering local host joomla site to live domain database issue

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin, joomla3.0

I'm transferring my localhost Joomla site to my Telekom live domain , problem is when transferring the database.

I have created the export from my local host database. The dump I'm trying to import into the phpmyadmin provided by the service provider
The problem is that when I import it comes up with the error

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, < unknown> and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

I have been stuck for days, please help me guys !
I'm using Wampserver for Windows

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message tells you? `Please contact the server administrator`

Comment: no not yet i thought it might just be some simple problem in the dump sql file maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

It's an internal error, and the server isn't giving you, or us, any information to help you out. Your best bet is to contact Telekom, and ask them to look in their server logs, so they can investigate the problem.

Provide them with as much information as you can, give them any relevant information: the name of the server where your db is hosted (they often show that in your CPanel), the name of the database where you're trying to dump the data, and if you're willing and able to do so, provide them with the sql file you exported from localhost. This helps them to diagnose the problem as efficiently as possible.

Comment: Usual suspects are memory allocation issues and timeouts. Have you tried splitting the sql into multiple parts - and make sure to zip (or tar and gzip) the files, so as to save upload time.

Comment: @DeanMarshall You provided an answer in your comment. If you post it as an answer, user3744095 can accept it if it works.